# Getting the 0-255 values from a pixel in a ppm file C

Tags: c, rgb, ppm

Ok, so I have code that will read in the header from a ppm image, allocate memory for the size of the image, and will successfully print the blank spots (a random number repeated in terminal) for each pixel.  All I need to know is how I am supposed to read in the red green and blue values (the 3 separate values ranging from 0-255) for each pixel.  I don't know how to access this data within each pixel.  Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int subscript(int row,int column,int numberColumns);
int sub(int rd, int gr, int bl);
//table of contents for the subscript
int main(void){
        char header[5];
        scanf("%s",header);
        printf("%s",header);
        printf("\n");
        int width, height, depth;
        scanf("%d %d %d\n", &width, &height, &depth);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", width, height, depth);
        int red = 0;
        int green = 0;
        int blue = 0;
        int sm;
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        //allocate memory for bit to be used throughout main
        unsigned char *bit = malloc(width*height);
        int *rgb = malloc(3*depth);
        //loops to read in table and print it
        while(r < height){
                while(c < width)
                        {
                        int col;
                        scanf("%d",&col);
                        //brings in allocated memory and values
                        bit[subscript(r,c,width)] = col;
                        int clr;
                        rgb[sub(red,green,blue)] = clr; 
                        int color = clr + col;
                        printf(" %d",clr);
                        c=c+1;
                        }
                printf("\n");
                r = r + 1;
                c = 0;
                }


        free(bit);

}
int subscript(int row,int column, int numberColumns)
        {
        return row * numberColumns + column;
        //retuns items for subscript
}

int sub(int rd, int gr, int bl)
        {
        return rd+gr+bl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[PPM files](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) store colours as triples of bytes (one byte each for r, g, and b in that order) if the maximum colour value field in the header is less than 256 and triples of two bytes if it is 256 or greater (so two bytes for each of r, g, and b, again in that order).

In the two bytes per channel case, the bytes are MSB first (big-endian).

---

`scanf("%c", &byte_var);` will read you a single character (byte) into `byte_var`, which should be an appropriate type. You can then process it accordingly. `scanf("%hhu", &byte_var);` will read an unsigned character if you are using C99 - if you are using C89 you should look up `getchar`.

Now, `scanf` returns the number of successfully converted arguments or EOF, so you should be checking the result for both incorrect input and the end of input.
For example:

```
int n;
char c;

while ((n = scanf("%c", &c)) != EOF && 1 == n) {
    // do something
}
```

An example use of this would be:

```
// Read width, height, work out how many bytes you need per pixel.
...

// Now read some pixels
// Here I assume one byte per pixel; this would be a good situation
// to use a function for reading different channel widths

w = 0, h = 0;
while ((n = scanf("%hhu%hhu%hhu", &r, &g, &b)) != EOF && 3 == n
        && w < width && h < height) {
  // now do something with r, g, b
  // e.g. store them in an appropriate pixels array at pixels[w][h] 
  ...

  ++w;
  if (w == width) {
    w = 0, ++h;
  }
}
```

I also see you are reading from `stdin`, which I find a bit unusual since the title indicates you are working with a file. You can open a file with `fopen` (don't forget to check the result), use `fscanf` to read from it, and use `fclose` to close it afterwards.

However, I suggest reading the whole file into memory and processing it there, because reading a file a few bytes at a time is slow.

---

Last, I note that you are only allocating `width` * `height` bytes for `bit` when you need `bytes_per_channel` * `num_channels` * `width` * `height`, not checking whether your `malloc` failed, not freeing `rgb`. You should fix these things.

Comment: it's for a project, and one of the requirements is to parse the input/output of the file from the command line, so I don't think I'm allowed to use fopen in this situation.  I've seen in several other posts that reading the whole file into memory is much faster, but I have to read it in piece by piece so I don't go outside of the material we've covered in class (an unfortunate redundancy here).  How could I go about incorporating that scanf that you mentioned into the nested row/column loop?  I will fix the malloc issues you mentioned as well.

Comment: "from command line" could mean that the filename is to be passed as an argument to your program or that it is to be piped via stdin. Do whatever you have to do for your assignment. I'll add an example re. the loop etc.

Comment: @ihavethedumb Added example.

Comment: Here's an example of what I need.  I will try to use what you suggested:                                                        1. Read in an image file in PPM format. PPM files are plain text files that look like this:
P6
width height
maximum color depth
red green blue for each pixel (ranging from 0 to 255), in binary format.
The order of the pixels is row by row, so you’ll want to read them in in loops that look like this:
For each row
      For each column
          Read in pixel and store at image array in that spot
no image will exceed 500 (width) x 500 (height).

Comment: 2. Parse command line arguments to figure out which filter to apply and where to save the file. The command line
arguments will be in the format:
./a.out inputfilename.ppm outputfilename.ppm filtername
3. Apply that filter to the image.
4. Output the filtered image to the output file.

Comment: that's what I meant by the command line arguments.  It looks like what you posted earlier with the example of the scanf might work, I will try to tidy up my malloc problems, add the scanf into my loop, and I'll get back to you.  Thanks for the help.